# PostgreSQL server not listening

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I installed PostgreSQL about a month ago on Ubuntu 21.04, using the command `sudo apt install postgresql`, and then forgot about it until today. Today, I tried psql and got an error indicating it's not listening on a Unix domain socket:

```
$ sudo -i -u postgres psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
$
```

`netstat` shows that it's not listening on port 5432 either.

Port 5432 is not being blocked by any firewall or other anti-malware: I am able to do `nc -l -p 5432` and connect to it from another machine.

I've tried checking other things:

```
$ sudo systemctl is-active postgresql
active
$ sudo systemctl is-enabled postgresql
enabled
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2021-07-20 12:38:20 BST; 3 weeks 1 days ago
    Process: 706 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 706 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 20 12:38:20 pluto systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jul 20 12:38:20 pluto systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
$ ls -al /etc/postgresql
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 postgres postgres  4096 Feb 26 00:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 163 root     root     12288 Aug 11 08:36 ..
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner Data directory Log file
$
```

Was there some setup that I was supposed to do following `apt install` that I haven't done in order to get the server running?

Comment: Your server is crashing. `code=exited`... `Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS`

Comment: @OneCricketeer no it is not (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS). `postgresql.service` is a bootstrap process that launches the actual Postgres instance(s) and the exits. The actual services will be `postgresql@<ver>-<cluster>.service`.

Comment: Run `pg_lsclusters` and add the results returned to your question. Read this [Ubuntu Postgres](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/databases-postgresql) and see if you missed anything.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, added. It shows no clusters.

Comment: `ExecStart=/bin/true` <<-- this looks like a stub. Maybe a configuration/installation problem?

Comment: @wildplasser, it is not a configuration/installation problem. Read my previous comment above. It is doing what it supposed to.

Comment: Well: it failed to start. Either by misconfiguration (directory/access rights), or by failing recovery. In any case: check the logfile(s) It is all there.

Comment: No it did not fail to start. Look at the timestamps,  they are from when the OP initially installed Postgres a month ago and I'm guessing it was started as part of that process. I'm also guessing there was no instance set to start automatically in the meantime.  If you want to know more see [Debian Postgres](https://wiki.debian.org/PostgreSql#Installation). For even more info see [postgresql-common](https://github.com/petere/postgresql-common).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to hints from @AdrianKlaver in his comments, I've got the server running by using these commands:

```
$ sudo -i -u postgres
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/initdb -D /tmp/pgdata  #In /tmp as I'm just playing with it
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_ctl -D /tmp/pgdata -l logfile start
```

This allows me to connect to the server, which is listening on port 5432, but I'm not sure how to make it start every time I reboot.

Comment: You want to use `sudo systemctl start postgresql` as that will use the Debian/Ubuntu packaging configuration to correctly start the Postgres instance or instances(as you can have multiple server running). To control the mode of starting go to `/etc/postgresql/13/main` and modify as the comments show e.g. `auto` for start on load.

Comment: Do you realise that `/tmp/*` is cleared at boot time by most linux/unix systems?